# How to traverse a property folder and get the path of each property file

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a folder called `Config/DEVLOCAL/mail.properties` and `config/client/local//DEVLOCAL/RDOClient/client.properties`. In my code I need to overwrite the properties file with my new values.

I did it by giving the exact path of the folder but my task it to get the properties file path which I have defined in the environment variable and pass it accordingly. I should not hardcode the properties file path.

```java
PropertyFolderConfiguration propconfig = new PropertyFolderConfiguration();
PropertiesConfiguration rdoconfig =
    new PropertiesConfiguration("E:/Sriram Workspace/telmed_wrkspc/Config/DEVLOCAL/RDOClient/client.properties");    
PropertiesConfiguration mailconfig = 
    new PropertiesConfiguration("E:/Sriram Workspace/telmed_wrkspc/Config/DEVLOCAL/mail.properties");
```

Comment: You might want to check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

might help you, so your code will look like

```
PropertiesConfiguration rdoconfig = 
  new PropertiesConfiguration(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Config/DEVLOCAL/RDOClient/client.properties");
```

(I assume `E:/Sriram Workspace/telmed_wrkspc` is your working directory)

Also, you might want to use `File.separator` instead of slashes